# How can I reduce Stanford parser time of execution?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Good Morning,

I am using Stanford part of speech for my application, and I need to parse many text files (can go to 20 files). However I noticed that stanford takes a lot of time (sometimes 30min or more), the problem is that Stanford automatically builds the syntax tree, even when I don't need it.
Have anyone face this problem before? what can I do to reduce the parsing time of stanford?

Any help is welcome,
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want part of speech, not parse trees, you should run a (sequence model) part of speech tagger, such as the [Stanford POS Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml), which is orders of magnitude faster).  See the [Stanford Parser FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#m).  (If you want fast tagging, use the  `left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger` model of the Stanford POS Tagger.)